# How to write unit test for Reflection and performSelector?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, objective-c++

I have some objective c code like the following,

```
- (void *)myMethod {
    Class A = NSClassFromString(@"A");
    id val = [A performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"someMethod")];
    // code...
}
```

Then how can I mock the return value `val` within unit tests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `val` as it is cannot be unit tested. I you can modify the code, I suggest to replace the string `@"someMethod"` by a `var`, e.g. `var someMethod = @"someMethod"`. In your unit test, you can then set `someMethod` to any other string, and call a mocked method.